# Batch File task in windows - Find and replace across multiple files

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have to write a batch file which finds and replaces values of version and build with their new values given by the user as an input.

The user initially gives 3 values: Apps, version and build values (the new values).
The search is then made across multiple `.property` files in a folder. The Apps value is searched across multiple files and wherever there is a match, the version and build of that file will be replaced by the values given by the user.

Answer (score 0):

To Find and replace across multiple files easily, use [FART](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/)!